# selecting multiple group in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, schema

Display the medal count of CAN, USA and MEX for the year 2000. Write a CASE statement to display the full name of Countries in the output dataset. CAN: Canada, USA: United States of America and MEX: Mexico. Sort the data based on Medal.
How to solve the question by showing three columns. my answer is showing invalid relational operator. what to be fixed in the answer?

| Country | Medal | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Gold | 3 |
| CAN | Gold | 2[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTl98.png) |

[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3hej.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoveflow.

Please do not post images of code / Table Structure.

Please post it as text to attract answers

Answer (score 1):

If your data looks like here...

```sql
WITH
    tbl (NOC, MEDAL) AS
        (
            Select 'USA', 'Gold'    From Dual Union All
            Select 'MEX', 'Silver'  From Dual Union All
            Select 'CAN', 'Gold'    From Dual Union All
            Select 'MEX', 'Bronze'  From Dual Union All
            Select 'USA', 'Gold'    From Dual Union All
            Select 'USA', 'Bronze'  From Dual Union All
            Select 'USA', 'Gold'    From Dual 
        )
```

... and if you want to count how many particular medals a country won then you could use Count() Over() analytic fuunction, with DISTINCT keyword to eliminate duplicates. Note: DISTINCT could bee performance costly in case of large datasets.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
          Case  When NOC = 'CAN'    Then 'Canada'
                When NOC = 'MEX'    Then 'Mexico'
                When NOC = 'USA'    Then 'United States of America'
          Else  NOC
          End "COUNTRY",
          MEDAL "MEDAL",
          Count(MEDAL) Over(Partition By NOC, MEDAL) "MEDAL_COUNT"
FROM    tbl
ORDER BY Case MEDAL 
                WHEN 'Gold' THEN 1
                WHEN 'Silver' THEN 2
         Else 3
         End
--
--  R e s u l t :
COUNTRY                  MEDAL  MEDAL_COUNT
------------------------ ------ -----------
United States of America Gold             3 
Canada                   Gold             1 
Mexico                   Silver           1 
Mexico                   Bronze           1 
United States of America Bronze           1
```

If you want to count total number of medals per country then:

```sql
SELECT    Case  When NOC = 'CAN'    Then 'Canada'
                When NOC = 'MEX'    Then 'Mexico'
                When NOC = 'USA'    Then 'United States of America'
          Else  NOC
          End "COUNTRY",
          Count(MEDAL) "TOTAL_MEDALS"
FROM    tbl
GROUP BY  NOC  
ORDER BY  Count(MEDAL) DESC
--
--  R e s u l t :
COUNTRY                  TOTAL_MEDALS
------------------------ ------------
United States of America            4 
Mexico                              2 
Canada                              1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just learning how to write case statements. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataset contains a column named Country with values "CAN", "USA", "MEX", and a column named Medal with the medal type, here's a SQL statement that will display the full name of countries and sort the data based on the medal:

SELECT
CASE Country
WHEN 'CAN' THEN 'Canada'
WHEN 'USA' THEN 'United States of America'
WHEN 'MEX' THEN 'Mexico'
ELSE Country
END AS Full_Country,
Medal
FROM table_name
ORDER BY Medal;

Replace table_name with the name of your actual table. This statement will return a dataset with two columns: Full_Country (with the full name of the country) and Medal. The CASE statement checks the value of the Country column and returns the corresponding full name. If the value of Country is not "CAN", "USA", or "MEX", the statement will return the original value of Country. The dataset is then sorted based on the Medal column.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a new learner of case statement. Can you please tell me how to count the medals . Do I need to write separate statements for counting the medals won by each country? I have uploaded schema table. You can see that. I need to find medal count as well